Use Calculus results (not numeric integration methods) to approximate definite integral
Consider
$$
\int_{-1}^2 e^{-x^2}dx
$$
How can I approximate its value using Calculus theory? That is, not using numerical methods such as the trapezoid rule taught in Numerical Mathematics courses?
Ideas:

Riemann sums (but seems too coarse).
Use the fact the integral of the function over all the reals equals $\sqrt{\pi}$, but I am not sure how to use it.
Mean Value Theorem, but again I am not sure how to use it (how to choose the point).
Taylor series.

Any ideas?

Taylor series seems very efficient.

Some context might be useful here. Are there any considerations such as computational complexity, size of numbers involved, applicability to other limits or integrals to take into account?

@AnneBauval that was my first thought too. Trying it out, it seems slower than I expected: $20$ terms of the integrated Taylor series expansion only give an accuracy of $8$ decimal places. But this is just because of the rates of growth of factorial and of powers of $4$ involved; the rate of improvement in accuracy with number of terms should increase. The interesting implication of this is that this method is much slower to converge when $|x|$ is large, where you would expect methods such as the trapezium or Simpson's rule to do better.

Wikipedia recommends the Bürmann series.

This is an extremely weird question: "How do I do something, without using the methods designed for doing that very thing?" Except, it is not even clear where you are drawing the line between what can be used and what cannot be used. Calculus is the mathematics of refining approximations. Integration is defines by refining approximations. Riemann sums are Numerical Mathematics. Truncated Taylor series are Numerical Mathematics. The mean value theorem where you estimate the point by choosing some middle location is Numerical Mathematics. Start being reasonable, please.

I confess, my comment "Wikipedia recommends the Bürmann series" is somehow sneaky, the main message is not Bürmann series, it's Wikipedia. It makes obvious, $\displaystyle\int \exp(-x^2)\ dx$ is the error function (aka Gauss error function) without factor $2/\sqrt{\pi}$.
That is why $$\int_{-1}^2 e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\left(\mathrm{erf}(2)+\mathrm{erf}(1)\right)}{2}$$
So far results using "Calculus theory" as requested. Next step, the approximation. I'd suggest to lookup this table for the values of erf(x). Next, divide by $2$ is not a subject of approximation me think. Then, multiply by $\sqrt{\pi}$, there comes handy a slide rule, elsewise tables of logarithms, or maybe -- if not barred by rejected numerical methods -- a pocket calculator.
(BTW, I checked the result with an unwanted numerical method, and for me the approximation is acceptable.)
